# Has anyone used COPASI via commandline?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to run COPASI in commandline but there is very little documentation.

I have downloaded and unzipped binary, I am not sure how to proceed in order to do something as simple as import an SBML file?

Here is all the documentation I found:
http://copasi.org/Support/User_Manual/Model_Creation/Commandline_Version_and_Commandline_Options/

It doesn't say which command do I use to call COPASI?

Answer (score 0):

The command line version of COPASI is `CopasiSE`, which you can install besides the GUI `CopasiUI` via any source here http://copasi.org/Download/.

For example, see https://github.com/ICB-DCM/solverstudy/blob/master/Bash_Scripts/install_copasi.sh, in which case the executable resides in a local folder.

Regarding usage, I am not sure whether extensive API documentation is available. It probably won't help much, but here's how we wrapped it in a study via Python to call an underlying CPS model file https://github.com/ICB-DCM/solverstudy/blob/master/Python_Scripts/simulation_wrapper_copasi.py#L77.